# Dualization of the subproblem in bilevel programs

Tags: optimization, bilevel-optimization

Let's say we have the following problem

$$\max_{x∈X}(cx - \min_{y∈Y}dxy)$$

where $x$ and $y$ are decision variables and $c$ and $d$ are parameters. Then, we take the dual of the inner maximization problem.

Assume that this is the new objective function of the inner problem:

$$\max_{z∈Z}(mz)$$

where $m$ is a parameter and $z$ is the dual variable.

After that, how do we handle the $-$ sign before the inner minimization problem. Do we only multiply the new objective function like given below or do we need to follow a different path?

$$\max_{x∈X,z∈Z}(cx - mz)$$

Why I am asking this is, after multiplying by minus, I observe that I end up having an unbounded problem. Do we need to change the constraints of the subproblem as well?

Answer (score 2):

First, your $Z$ should actually be $Z(x),$ since the feasible region of the dual of the inner problem depends on $x.$

Second, $$\max_{x\in X, z\in Z(x)}(cx - mz) \neq \max_{x\in X}(cx - \max_{z\in Z(x)} mz)$$ since, for any given value of $x,$ the left side looks for the value of $z$ that makes $mz$ as small as possible and the right side looks for the value of $z$ that makes $mz$ as large as possible.

Comment: Is there any way to handle this sort of problem apart from Benders decomposition? I think Benders should work. But I am looking for other possible ways.

Comment: I don't think that can be answered without more information (whether variables are continuous or integer, whether there are joint constraints or whether $Y$ is independent of $x$, whether $X$ and $Y$ are polyhedral, ...).